# Max and min height for a BST

Tags: algorithms, trees

In order to find the maximum and minimum height for a BST, how would you go about doing it can’t quite find a good explanation online.

For example if you had 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 nodes/keys which are inserted into some order in an empty BST. Would prefer if there was an example where it's drawn out so I can visualise the insertions as well.

Comment: What do you want to hear? $n$ and $\log n$. For the first insert ordered sequence. For the later build a balanced bst, fill it appropriately and the sequence which builds it should be read by levels (i.e. 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7)

Comment: @dEmigOd like what are the rules to build it like how you mentioned above

Comment: I suppose in most general settings BST is unbalanced. You follow the very simple algorithm. We want to add value $w$. At node with value $v$, you turn left, if $w \leq v$ and right otherwise. If got to nowhere - create leaf with value $w$.

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a crack now!